# Set width of a frozen column

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I'm trying to use Frozen Column from [PrimeFaces ShowCase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/scroll.xhtml).

But I can't set the width of the first frozen column, this is really too wide.

[image: Exemple]

Someone could told me how to fix it ?

XHTML :

```
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{dtScrollView.cars}" 
             scrollable="true" scrollHeight="150"
             scrollWidth="300" frozenColumns="1">
   <p:column headerText="Id" footerText="Model">
      <h:outputText value="#{car.model}" />
   </p:column>
   <p:column headerText="Year" footerText="Year">
      <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
   </p:column>  
</p:dataTable>
```

I'm using PrimeFaces 5.0.

Comment: Do you experience [this](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=37719) kind of problem/s, when you edit/update a row held by a `<p:dataTable>` with frozen column/s using a `<p:rowEditor/>`? A `<p:dataTable>` with frozen column/s doesn't function properly, when a row in it is updated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to change the width of the frozen columns, use the following CSS class:

```
/* Change frozen width */
.ui-datatable-frozenlayout-left {
   width: 20%;
}
```

Here's an [online Demo](http://jsf.hatemalimam.com/DailyLab/frozenTable/main.xhtml), and a sample code on [github](https://github.com/hatemalimam/DailyLab/blob/master/src/main/webapp/frozenTable/main.xhtml).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code

```
<p:column headerText="Id" footerText="Model" style="width:20px;">
    <h:outputText value="#{car.model}" />
</p:column>
```

You can change the width value like you want

Answer (score -1):

hy,

add attribute style in `<p:column>` like this:

```
<p:column headerText="Id" footerText="Model" style="width: 10%;">
                <h:outputText value="#{car.model}" />
            </p:column>
```

try it, and is ok :)

[image]

Comment: i have update my responce and i have try :) is work; don't forget vote :)

Comment: change scrollHeight="150" scrollWidth="300" to scrollHeight="550" scrollWidth="800" and try