# Primefaces fixed width frozen column and expandable scroll area

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-datatable, frozen-columns

I'm going by the Primefaces showcase to add a frozen column to a datatable. Their setup has you set a fixed width for the scrollable area, and the frozen column area expands horizontally to fill whatever's left.

https://primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/scroll.xhtml?jfwid=6b3c1 -> See Frozen Columns

I'd like to have it setup the opposite way, with a fixed width for the frozen column (red area), and the scrollable area (blue area) expands to fill the horizontal space.

[image]

Has anyone run into this problem before?

I've tried using CSS calc() to set the width of the blue area to something like 100% - [red area width] but it doesn't seem to recognize the value of calc().

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24116639/502366 ?